# Kolmogorov–Smirnov vs Brunner-Munzel

Tags: nonparametric, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

What are the main differences between the two-sample Kolmogorov–Smirnov test and the Brunner-Munzel test with respect to assumptions, power, etc? Both are non-parametric, and should work in the heteroscedastic case?

Comment: I believe these tests are quite different. The [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) is used to test if two samples come from the same distribution. The [Brunner-Munzel test](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/%28SICI%291521-4036%28200001%2942:1%3C17::AID-BIMJ17%3E3.0.CO;2-U/abstract) is a generalisation of the Behrens-Fisher problem with possible ties in the samples. The null hypothesis here is $H_0: p=P(X<Y)+0.5P(X=Y)=0.5$, where $X\sim F$ and $Y\sim G$. Yes, both should work in the heteroscedastic case.

Comment: @Procrastinator: Could you clarify what it means for the KS test to "work in the heteroscedastic case" given that this is a test on the equality of *distributions* from two iid samples?

Comment: @cardinal By 'both should work in the heteroscedastic case' I meant that the observations in each sample come from the same distribution. This is, you have two samples $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$ and $y=(y_1,...,y_m)$, where $x_j\sim F$ and $y_i \sim G$. Therefore there is no assumption about the variance (if it exists) of $x$ and $y$ (or the corresponding variables). Is this what you asked me to clarify?

Comment: @Procrastinator Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Alexander: I think it would help to clarify what you mean by *heteroscedastic*. Normally I would think of that as variation *within* a set of observations, not differences in variation *between* two sets of observations (which, if I'm not mistaken, is how @Procrastinator appears to have interpreted it). Can you briefly clarify this? Saying the KS tests works in the former case does not make too much sense, but it *can* in the latter case (e.g., if you mean by "work" that it will reject the null hypothesis in large enough samples). Thanks.

Comment: @cardinal I thought about differences in variation between two sets of observations, i.e., exactly how Procrastinator has interpreted it.

Comment: @Procrastinator, if you can make an answer out of your comment I will accept it.